# How to make infinite scroll work with react and intersection api while lazily fetching data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intersection-observer

Tried react and it's intersection api for the first time.

I might be missing some basics. **Please do explain while pointing out the errors.**

I ma trying to make an infinite scroll with lazy loading of images from an api call.

The moment I hit bottom, I make one more api call to fetch more data ,

so that I get an infinite scroll.

```
  if(loading) {
    return <p>Loading data...</p>
  }
  return (

    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <div style={{height: "400px"}}>
        <ul>
          {!loading && data.map((url,index)=> 
            <li><img src={url} alt="" width="200" height="200" /></li>
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div ref={setElement} style={{background: "transparent"}}>Load More</div>
    </div>
  );
```

So basically I just map over data where I can few urls and show images accordingly.

There is a div **"Load More"** when I come to it. I need to show loading indicator again and try fetching data and show more images and so on.

These states I have defined by `useReducer`

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
    loading: false,
    data: []
  });

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "startLoadingData":
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
        data: []
      };
    case "loadMoreData":
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        data: state.data.concat(action.payload) // Did it so that I do not mess the existing images on top
      };
    default:
      throw new Error("Cannott parse action");
  }
};
```

But the way I set `interSection api` and `side effect caused by that` my page going in and infinite loop.

And I have no idea why.

```
  const [element, setElement] = useState(null); // create a ref to the div element at bottom

  const loadData = () => {

      dispatch({type: "startLoadingData"});
      axios.all([axios.get('https://aws.random.cat/meow'),
              axios.get('https://random.dog/woof.json')])
        .then(axios.spread((catResponse, dogResponse) => {  
            console.log(catResponse.data,dogResponse.data);
            let response = [];
            response.push(catResponse.data.file);
            response.push(dogResponse.data.url);
            dispatch({type:"loadMoreData", payload: response})
        }))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  const observer = useRef(
      new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
        let first = entries[0].isIntersecting;
        console.log(first);
        if(first) {
          loadData();
        }
      },{threshold: 1})
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    let currentElement = element;
    let currentObserver = observer.current;
     if(currentElement) {
      currentObserver.observe(element);
    }

    return () => {
      if(currentElement) {
        currentObserver.unobserve(element)
      }
    }  
  },[element]);
```

Whenever `element` dependency changes, I am trying the same. But not working.

Please explain what am I missing?

Online code link : `https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-egkdqy`

Comment: Not seeing your code in the sandbox

Comment: @DcoderZ Added the complete code

Comment: The link: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-pnfp8 is to a counter example still not seeing your code.

Comment: @DcoderZ I know because of some issue. I added the entire index.js below the question itself.

Comment: thanks I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

It looks to be working fine with this:

```
case "loadMoreData":
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        data: [...state.data, ...action.payload]
      };
```

As you scroll down it hits load more then fetches two more images.